# Showing images from a secure domain on Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, authentication

I'm receiving emails from our test server which I need to be able to fully view, but the test server is secured with a username and password so the images don't display in my Thunderbird client.

Is there anyway to provide Thunderbird with this info (just as I can with FF or Chrome) so it will show the images from now on?

**EDIT**
I'm using Thunderbird 17.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the image URL? Then you could use this scheme:

```
 <img src="http://user:pass@host/image.jpg">
```

Comment: So far the only solution that could work but putting our secure server's username and password in our emails sort of defeats the purpose of having one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [AutoAuth](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/autoauth/) add-on? It hasn't been updated for a couple of years, and the highest tested version of Thunderbird is 15.0a1, but it's worth a try.

Comment: AutoAuth isn't compatible with TB17.